# How to get the variable value in the function which is called inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to call a function inside another function. Now the sub function has a value which is want to be show in alert message.

Take a look at the code that I have written so far :

```js
var subFunction = function(){
  var subValue = "sub value";
}

var mainFunction = function(){
  subFunction();
  alert(subValue);
}

mainFunction();
```

I'm getting an error message saying that the subValue is not defined.

I want to use the value of a variable present in the subfunction in the main function, How do I do that?

Please help thanks in advance :)

Comment: `subvalue` only exists in `subFunction` scope. Hence, the error "subValue is not defined".

Answer (score 4):

Return the subfunction's value

```
var subFunction = function(){
  var subValue = "sub value";
  return subValue;
}

var mainFunction = function(){
  var test = subFunction();
  alert(test);
}

mainFunction();
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a question of scoping.  The variable subValue is only accessible inside subFunction.  You can either make this a global variable (may not be desirable) or return this value from the subFunction like this:

```
var subFunction = function(){
  var subValue = "sub value";
  return subValue;
}

var mainFunction = function(){
  var sv = subFunction();
  alert(sv);
}

mainFunction();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var subValue = "";

var subFunction = function(){
  subValue = "sub value";
}

var mainFunction = function(){
  subFunction();
  alert(subValue);
}

mainFunction();
```

As this code `subValue` variable should be a class scope variable.

Comment: This assumes OP wants to change scope of `subValue`, which is not what was requested

Answer (score 0):

The question is, what do you want with the result? Basically, you need to expose the value in a form, you can use it.

1. Just return the value

```js
var subFunction = function () {
        var subValue = "sub value";
        return subValue;            // <---
    },
    mainFunction = function(){
        console.log(subFunction());
    };

mainFunction();
```

2. Use a global or a variable in outer scope

```js
var subFunction = function () {
        var subValue = "sub value";
        returnValue = subValue;     // <---
    },
    mainFunction = function () {
        subFunction();
        console.log(returnValue);
    },
    returnValue;                    // <---

mainFunction();
```

3. Store it as a property of the calling function

```js
var subFunction = function () {
        var subValue = "sub value";
        subFunction.subValue = subValue; // <---
    },
    mainFunction = function () {
        subFunction();
        console.log(subFunction.subValue);
    };

mainFunction();
```